# How to get current folder path in visual studio code

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I am trying to get current project folder path in visual studio code but not working.I have searched in google but no use.Anyone can help me?

```
var vscode = require("vscode");
var path = require("path");
function activate(context) {
   var currentlyOpenfileprojectname = 
   vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri.fsPath;  

}
```